# Syncing a Sub Folder of a Github repo to a separate github repository

Tags: git, github

So I have a repository on Github

AUserName/mainRepo with the structure

- README.md
- Project A/
- Project B/

and two separate repos

- AUserName/ProjectA
- AUserName/ProjectB

I want the contents of Folder "Project A" in AUserName/mainRepo to be sync with the repo AUserName/ProjectA.

Every time a Pull request gets merged with changes in the content of folders **Project A** and **Project B**, I want to sync the changes to the individual repos (AUserName/ProjectA, AUserName/ProjectB)

How would I do this?

Comment: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.txt